# MIP problem with gekko - It doesn't converge to a solution neither returns an error

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

I am working on a space planning problem where I try to minimize the distances between the pieces of equipment in order to reduce the cost of piping between them, which is a Mixed Interger Programming problem.  The constraints are described as comments in the code.

```
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
#parameters
ax = m.Array(m.Const, (7,1))
ax[0,0]= 1.4
ax[1,0]= 3.2
ax[2,0]= 2.0
ax[3,0]= 4.2
ax[4,0]= 4.2
ax[5,0]= 4.0
ax[6,0]= 1.4

by = m.Array(m.Const, (7,1))
by[0,0]= 1.2
by[1,0]= 2.8
by[2,0]= 1.2
by[3,0]= 2.0
by[4,0]= 2.0
by[5,0]= 4.0
by[6,0]= 1.2

#variables
w = m.Array(m.Var,(7,1),lb=0)
d = m.Array(m.Var,(7,1),lb=0)
x = m.Array(m.Var,(7,1),lb=0)
y = m.Array(m.Var,(7,1),lb=0)
R = m.Array(m.Var,(7,7),lb=0)
L = m.Array(m.Var,(7,7),lb=0)
A = m.Array(m.Var,(7,7),lb=0)
B = m.Array(m.Var,(7,7),lb=0)
Dist = m.Array(m.Var,(7,7),lb=0)
C = m.Array(m.Const,(7,7),value=0)
COST = m.Var()


#binary variables
o = m.Array(m.Var,(7,1),value=0,lb=0,ub=1,integer=True)
zx = m.Array(m.Var,(7,7),value=0,lb=0,ub=1,integer=True)
zy = m.Array(m.Var,(7,7),value=0,lb=0,ub=1,integer=True)

#cost of piping between each piece
C[0,1]=1
C[1,3]=1
C[1,4]=2
C[2,3]=1
C[4,4]=1
C[3,6]=1
C[4,5]=1
C[5,6]=1




# 1-D equations###########################
for i in range(7):
    #calculating the dimension w and d, according to the orientation to the x and y axis
    m.Equation(w[i,0]==ax[i,0]*o[i,0]+by[i,0]*(1- o[i,0]))
    m.Equation(d[i,0]==ax[i,0]+by[i,0]- w[i,0])
    #the pieces have to be whole inside the given area
    m.Equation(x[i,0]>=w[i,0]/2)
    m.Equation(y[i,0]>=d[i,0]/2)
    m.Equation(x[i,0]+w[i,0]/2 <= 10)
    m.Equation(y[i,0]+d[i,0]/2 <= 10)

#2-D Equations##################################
for i in range(7):
    for j in range(7):
        while j > i :
         #calculating the distances between the pieces 
         m.Equation(R[i,j]-L[i,j]==x[i,0]-x[j,0])
         m.Equation(A[i,j]-B[i,j]==y[i,0]-y[j,0])
         m.Equation(Dist[i,j]==R[i,j]+L[i,j]+A[i,j]+B[i,j])

for i in range(7):
    for j in range(7):
        while j != i : 
            #pieces should not oversubscribe one another
            m.Equation(x[i,0]-x[j,0]+10*(1-zx[i,j])>=(w[i,0]+w[j,0])/2)
            m.Equation(y[i,0]-y[j,0]+10*(1-zy[i,j])>=(d[i,0]+d[j,0])/2)

for i in range(7):
    for j in range(7):
        while j > i :
            #logical constrains in order pieces not being oversubscribed
            m.Equation(zx[i,j]+zx[j,i]+zy[i,j]+zy[j,i]>=1) 
            m.Equation(zx[i,j]+zx[j,i]<=1)
            m.Equation(zy[i,j]+zy[j,i]<=1)

for i in range(7):
    for j in range(7):
        for k in range(7):
            m.Equation(zx[i,j]+zx[j,k]<= 1 + zx[i,k])
            m.Equation(zy[i,j]+zy[j,k]<= 1 + zy[i,k])
    
for i in range(7):
    for j in range(7):
        for k in range(7):
            for m in range(7):
                m.Equation(zx[i,j]+zx[j,k]+zx[k,m] <= 2 + zx[i,m])
                m.Equation(zy[i,j]+zy[j,k]+zy[k,m] <= 2 + zy[i,m])
for i in range(7):
    for j in range(7):
        while j > i :
            COST = C[i,j]*Dist[i,j]        


m.Minimize(COST)

m.options.SOLVER=1


m.solve(disp=True)


print(x)

print(y)
```

I am trying to have it converge to a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Check your Python book and make sure you understand what a `while` statement is doing.

You can also add a print statement:

```
#2-D Equations##################################
for i in range(7):
    for j in range(7):
        while j > i :
         #calculating the distances between the pieces 
         print(f"generating 2d equation i={i},j={j}")
         m.Equation(R[i,j]-L[i,j]==x[i,0]-x[j,0])
         m.Equation(A[i,j]-B[i,j]==y[i,0]-y[j,0])
         m.Equation(Dist[i,j]==R[i,j]+L[i,j]+A[i,j]+B[i,j])
```

I also suggest you learn how to use a debugger. Stepping through a program is often very illuminating.

The cleanest is probably to write the loop as:

```
N = 7 # don't sprinkle 7s throughout the code
for i in range(N):
   for j in range(i+1,N):
```

Comment: Thank you sir, the while loop was a blatant mistake from my side.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few issues:

1. The `while` condition creates an infinite loop. [Erwin Kalvelagen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5625534/erwin-kalvelagen) has a helpful suggestion to identify errors with a debugger as you step through the code.
2. The `m` index variable in the 4 nested loops redefines the gekko model object
3. The `COST` variable is redefined in a loop. This variable can be removed by including a `m.Minimize()` function in the loop.
4. The nested loops and number of integer variables takes about `10x` more time as the problem size `n` grows by one.
5. The cost of piping `C` appears to be a sparse matrix. Are there missing entries? The cost of piping `C` and other `m.Const` arrays can be `numpy` arrays.

Here is an updated problem that solves successfully with `n=5`. It is likely that `n=7` will also solve with more time.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

n = 5

#parameters
ax = m.Array(m.Const, (n,1))
ax[0,0]= 1.4
ax[1,0]= 3.2
ax[2,0]= 2.0
ax[3,0]= 4.2
ax[4,0]= 4.2
#ax[5,0]= 4.0
#ax[6,0]= 1.4

by = m.Array(m.Const, (n,1))
by[0,0]= 1.2
by[1,0]= 2.8
by[2,0]= 1.2
by[3,0]= 2.0
by[4,0]= 2.0
#by[5,0]= 4.0
#by[6,0]= 1.2

#variables
w = m.Array(m.Var,(n,1),lb=0)
d = m.Array(m.Var,(n,1),lb=0)
x = m.Array(m.Var,(n,1),lb=0)
y = m.Array(m.Var,(n,1),lb=0)
R = m.Array(m.Var,(n,n),lb=0)
L = m.Array(m.Var,(n,n),lb=0)
A = m.Array(m.Var,(n,n),lb=0)
B = m.Array(m.Var,(n,n),lb=0)
Dist = m.Array(m.Var,(n,n),lb=0)

#binary variables
o = m.Array(m.Var,(n,1),value=0,lb=0,ub=1,integer=True)
zx = m.Array(m.Var,(n,n),value=0,lb=0,ub=1,integer=True)
zy = m.Array(m.Var,(n,n),value=0,lb=0,ub=1,integer=True)

#cost of piping between each piece
C = np.zeros((n,n))
C[0,1]=1
C[1,3]=1
C[1,4]=2
C[2,3]=1
C[4,4]=1
#C[3,6]=1
#C[4,5]=1
#C[5,6]=1

# 1-D equations###########################
for i in range(n):
    #calculating the dimension w and d, according to the
    #  orientation to the x and y axis
    m.Equation(w[i,0]==ax[i,0]*o[i,0]+by[i,0]*(1- o[i,0]))
    m.Equation(d[i,0]==ax[i,0]+by[i,0]- w[i,0])
    #the pieces have to be whole inside the given area
    m.Equation(x[i,0]>=w[i,0]/2)
    m.Equation(y[i,0]>=d[i,0]/2)
    m.Equation(x[i,0]+w[i,0]/2 <= 10)
    m.Equation(y[i,0]+d[i,0]/2 <= 10)

#2-D Equations##################################
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if j > i :
            #calculating the distances between the pieces 
            m.Equation(R[i,j]-L[i,j]==x[i,0]-x[j,0])
            m.Equation(A[i,j]-B[i,j]==y[i,0]-y[j,0])
            m.Equation(Dist[i,j]==R[i,j]+L[i,j]+A[i,j]+B[i,j])

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if j != i : 
            #pieces should not oversubscribe one another
            m.Equation(x[i,0]-x[j,0]+10*(1-zx[i,j])>=(w[i,0]+w[j,0])/2)
            m.Equation(y[i,0]-y[j,0]+10*(1-zy[i,j])>=(d[i,0]+d[j,0])/2)

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if j > i :
            #logical constrains in order pieces not being oversubscribed
            m.Equation(zx[i,j]+zx[j,i]+zy[i,j]+zy[j,i]>=1) 
            m.Equation(zx[i,j]+zx[j,i]<=1)
            m.Equation(zy[i,j]+zy[j,i]<=1)

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        for k in range(n):
            m.Equation(zx[i,j]+zx[j,k]<= 1 + zx[i,k])
            m.Equation(zy[i,j]+zy[j,k]<= 1 + zy[i,k])
    
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        for k in range(n):
            for mm in range(n):
                m.Equation(zx[i,j]+zx[j,k]+zx[k,mm] <= 2 + zx[i,mm])
                m.Equation(zy[i,j]+zy[j,k]+zy[k,mm] <= 2 + zy[i,mm])
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if j > i :
            m.Minimize(C[i,j]*Dist[i,j])

m.options.SOLVER=1

m.solve(disp=True)

print(x)
print(y)
```

**Number of Variables and Solve Time with n = 3**

```
 Number of state variables:    327
 Number of total equations: -  264
 Number of slack variables: -  249
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :    -186

Solution Time: 0.8666 sec
```

**Number of Variables and Solve Time with n = 4**

```
 Number of state variables:    830
 Number of total equations: -  724
 Number of slack variables: -  698
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :    -592

Solution Time: 13.4302
```

**Number of Variables and Solve Time with n = 5**

```
 Number of state variables:    1790
 Number of total equations: -  1630
 Number of slack variables: -  1590
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :    -1430

Solution Time 103.57
```

Comment: Thank you sir for the answer and explanation! The C as the cost of piping is a sparse matrix because it represents the connections between some specific pieces of the equipment only and not every piece with all the others.